# ActiveRecord - Altering a table to set an auto increment minimum value?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

### Background

A simple rails activerecord migration

```
class CreateMyTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change    
    create_table :my_table, force: :cascade do |t|
      t.index    "id"
      t.string   "column1",     limit: 64
      t.string   "column2", limit: 64

      t.timestamps null: false
    end       
    MyTable.connection.execute("ALTER TABLE my_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;") 
  end
end
```

It creates `my_table` and adds a few columns to it. The last line executes a raw command to set the first `id` to start counting at 10000.

### The problem

When running `db:migrate` rails updates the `schema.rb` file to incorporate the result of this migration, which is adding the new table.

However the last statement setting the `AUTO_INCREMENT` doesn't get captured in the `schema.rb` file.

When another user or server runs `db:setup` for the first time rails will use that `schema.rb` to construct the schema and won't pick up the fact that it needs to bump the `id` to 10000.

Is there any way to get this migration change into the `schema.rb` file so that all future DB's constructed based off this `schema.rb` file will appropriately increment the `id`?

#### Edit

Based off the suggestion below by inye, I tried editing my migration to remove the `t.index` reference, and my `schema.rb` is as follows

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150501211519) do

  create_table "my_table", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "column1",    limit: 64
    t.string   "column2",    limit: 64
    t.datetime "created_at",            null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",            null: false
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
class CreateMyTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change    
        create_table :my_table, force: :cascade do |t|
            t.string   "column1",     limit: 64
            t.string   "column2", limit: 64

            t.timestamps null: false
        end       
        execute("ALTER TABLE my_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;")
    end
end
```

according to http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html you no need the line `t.index    "id"`

> A primary key column called id will also be added implicitly, as it's the default primary key for all Active Record models.

EDIT:

Other option is with `before_save` with some like

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :change_id

    def change_id

        last_model = Model.order("id DESC").first
        if last_model.id < 10000 or last_model.nil?
            self.id = 10000
        else
            self.id = last_model.id + 1
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: No luck, unfortunately. It executes the statements correctly the first time, but doesn't modify anything in `schema.rb`. The next time any machine uses that `schema.rb` file to re-construct the schema, it won't have any idea it needs to set the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value

Comment: try whit the edited answer and can you put your `my_table` schema?

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I tried removing the ID and it does work correctly the first time, but it's still not updating `schema.rb`. I added the output to my comment above.

Comment: the `id` of tables are not showing in the `schema.rb`

Comment: what happend if you insert one row in your table? what id you get?

Comment: Correct, I'm not sure why

Comment: It correctly inserts starting with `id` 10000. However if I drop my database entirely and re-create it, Rails uses `schema.rb` and ignore the `execute()` statement, so it inserts starting at `id` 1 again

Comment: maybe is better use `before_save` in you model and rewire your `id` entry

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking that something like that would be required. Instead of checking before each model save (using `before_save`), is there a way to run a check when the app starts up? I can just manually check the table and set the `AUTO_INCREMENT` if it has not been set yet.